# BaseAdapter explanation of the notifyDataSetChanged method

Tags: java, android, adapter

That's my code:

```
public void loadNavigationDrawerItems(){

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.setItems();


    //Log.d(TAG, "--> Reload Navigation Drawer");
}
```

is it correct? or is it better to mod it as this

```
public void loadNavigationDrawerItems(){


    adapter.setItems();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //Log.d(TAG, "--> Reload Navigation Drawer");
}
```

setItems is a method of the adapter that can load item in the adapter from an external class...
My question is if is better to call the notifyDataSetChanged before or after the setItems.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After.  You call it when the changes have finished happening and not before hand.  I'm guessing you are using a custom adapter.  So ideally, the `setItems()` method should be invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()` itself instead of having to rely on it happening externally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so is it possible to call the notifyDataSetChanged() directly from the adapter code? At the end of the setItems() method?

Comment: Yes. In fact, your adapter should be doing that for any method which mutates the underlying data.